# Measures of noncompactness in locally convex topological vector spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a Banach space and denote by $B(x,r)$ the closed ball centered at $x\in X$ and radius $r>0$. We recall that the Hausdorff measure of noncompactness (MNC) is defined as
$$
\beta(B):=\inf\{r>0 : B\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}B(x_{i},r),\textrm{ for some } x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\in X\}.
$$
for each non-empty and bounded $B\subset X$. The Kuratowski MNC is defined as
$$
\alpha(B):=\inf\{r>0 : B\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}D_{i},\textrm{ for some } D_{1},\ldots ,D_{n}\subset X, diam(D_{i})\leq r\}.
$$
where $diam(D_{i})$ is the diameter of $D_{i}$. For instance, if $X$ is the space of the continuos functions defined on $[0,1]$, for the set
$$
C:=\big\{f\in X: 0\leq f(0)\leq \frac{1}{3},0\leq f(x)\leq 1, \frac{2}{3}\leq f(1)\leq 1 \big\},
$$
I have read, without proof that $\alpha(C)=1$ and $\beta(C)=1/2$.

Now, assume $X$ is a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space (LCTVS), but not a Banach space, whose topology is generated a family of seminorms $P$. For each $p\in P$, we denote by $B_{p}(x,r):=\{y\in X:p(x-y)\leq r\}$ the closed "ball" defined by $p$. We can define in the class of bounded subsets of $X$ the function
$$
\beta_{p}(B):=\inf\{r>0 : B\subset \{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}+B_{p}(0,r),\textrm{ for some } x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\in X\}.
$$
Replacing, in the above definition of $\alpha$, $diam(D)$ by $diam_{p}(D):=\sup\{p(x-y):x,y\in D\}$ we obtain
$$
\alpha_{p}(B):=\inf\{r>0 : B\subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}D_{i},\textrm{ for some } D_{1},\ldots ,D_{n}\subset X, diam_{p}(D_{i})\leq r\}.
$$

Thus, the families $(\beta_{p})_{p\in P}$ and $(\alpha_{p})_{p\in P}$ are called, respectively, the Hausdorff and the Kuratowski MNC.

I am looking for an example where
$$
0<\beta_{p}(C)\neq \beta(C) \textrm{ and/or } 0<\alpha_{p}(C)\neq \alpha(C) \quad (*)
$$
for some closed and convex $C$ subset of $X$. My attempts have been the following.

Let $X$ be the Banach space of the continuos functions defined on $[0,1]$, and $C$ as above. Consider $X$ endowed the point-wise convergence topology. Such topology is generated by the seminorms $p_{x}(f):=|f(x)|$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. As $[0,1]$ is compact, given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite set, put $F=\{x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\}\subset [0,1]$ such that for each $x\in[0,1]$ there exists $x_{i}\in F$ such that $|x-x_{i}|\leq \varepsilon$. Then, by putting $f_{i}(x):=x_{i}$ for each $x\in [0,1]$, for each $x\in [0,1]$ for a given $f\in C$ there is $f_{i}$ such that
$$
p_{x}(f-f_{i})=|f(x)-f_{i}(x)|=|f(x)-x_{i}|\leq \varepsilon.
$$
So, $\beta_{p_{x}}(C)=0$. Likewise, $\alpha_{p_{x}}(C)=0$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. I am not sure if the above proof is correct at all, but if it is correct, (*) is not satisfied.

If $X$ is the space of the null sequences $c_{0}$ endowed the topology generated by the seminorms $p_{n}(x):=|x_{n}|$ for each $n\geq 1$ and $x:=(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in c_{0}$, I think (reasoning as above) that $\beta_{p_{n}}(B)=\alpha_{p_{n}}(B)=0$ for each $n\geq 1$, where $B$ stands for the unit closed ball of $c_{0}$. So, (*) is not satisfied in this case. Note that $\beta(B)=1$ and $\alpha(B)=2$ if $c_{0}$ is endowed its usual supremum norm.

Somebody know an example where (*) be satisfied?

Many thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

We can trivially provide the required examples as follows. Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be any Banach space. For any $\lambda>0$ and $x\in X$ put $p_\lambda(x)=\lambda\|x\|$. Then $p_\lambda$ is  a norm on $X$. We have $B_{p_\lambda}(x,r)=B(x,r/\lambda)$ for each $x\in X$ and $\operatorname{diam}_{p_\lambda}(D)=\lambda\operatorname{diam}(D)$ for any nonempty subset $D$ of $X$. It follows that $\beta_{p_\lambda}(B)=\lambda\beta(B)$ and $\alpha_{p_\lambda}(B)=\lambda\alpha(B)$ for any nonempty bounded subset $B$ of $X$. In particular, for the closed convex set $C$ from the question and any $\lambda\ne 1$ we have
$0<\beta_{p_\lambda}(C)=\lambda\beta(C)\ne \beta(C)$ and $0<\alpha_{p_\lambda}(C)=\lambda\alpha(C)\ne \alpha(C)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Really I am looking the example in a LCTVS which is not a Banach sapce (I have edited the post). It seems that, fixed $\lambda >0$,  your example is a Banach space with an equivalent norm. Thanks.

Comment: @user123043 As far as I remember, in all proofs for the answer but the last sentence we can relax the completeness of $X$, so the counterparts of the constructions and the claims should hold also for any normed space $X$. Concerning the last example, I expect the values of all $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s will be the same if we replace $X$ by any its dense subspace (for instance, of all polynomials on $[0,1]$)  and $C$ by $C\cap Y$.

Comment: Again, thanks for your response. I am looking for an example where the condition (*) be satisfied for a not Banach space. Sorry if the statement of the post is not very clear. As you pointed out, the space of polynomials in [0,1] is dense in the space of the continuous functions but is not complete. But,  I am not sure to understand yor proposition "replace $C$ by $C\cap Y$", What is "Y"?  What family of (all differents) semi-norms we need to use? I am not sure the MNC of $C\cap Y$ be equal to the MNC of $C$: in general $\beta(C\cap Y)\leq \beta(C)$  (the same for $\alpha$).

Comment: @user123043 I am sorry for the delay with the answer. Also I am sorry that I missed to wrote that $Y$ is that "any dense subspace of $X$". We can also assume that $Y\ne X$. We use the restrictions on $Y$ of the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and the seminorm $p_\lambda$. I expect that since $Y$ is dense in $X$ and the interior of $C$ is dense in $C$ (I assume that the space of the continuous functions defined on [0,1] is endowed with the uniform norm) then $\beta_{p_\lambda}(C\cap Y)=\beta_{p_\lambda}(C)$, $\beta(C)=\beta(C\cap Y)$, and the same for $\alpha$'s.

Comment: @user123043 For instance, we can prove that $\alpha(C\cap Y)=\alpha(C)$, where $\alpha(C\cap Y)$ is for the space $Y$ as follows.
The inequality $\alpha(C\cap Y)\le \alpha(C)$ is clear. On the other hand, for any $r>\alpha(C\cap Y)$ there exist natural $n$ and subsets $D_{1},\ldots ,D_{n}\subset Y$ of diameter at most $r$ each such that $C\cap Y\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}D_{i}$.

Comment: Then $C\subset \overline{C\cap Y}\subset \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}D_{i}}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{D_{i}}$, and for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have $\operatorname{diam}\overline{D_i}=\operatorname{diam}D_i \le r$, so $\alpha(C)\le \alpha(C\cap Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for yuor aclarations. I don't see the way to give you the bounty

Comment: @user123043 OK. If you need more details or examples with seminorms satisfying some additional conditions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I reitrate my gratitude for yuor useful help. I think that in the example of the post, the topology is, precisely, the weak topology. For this topology, the bounded susbsets are precompacts for this reason the MNC are equal to zeor in these examples.